# For loop not working properly while using push in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have a JSON response containing `pickUpLatitidute` & `pickUpLongitude`, I want to push these values into an array `waypts` so I tried a `for` loop.

Inside the `for` loop I am pushing the `pickUpLatitidute` & `pickUpLongitude`, but it is not working as I require.

Click the submit button and you will see what I am getting as a response.

I am getting the last `pickUpLatitidute` & `pickUpLongitude` values.

```js
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var res={
        "status": "success",
        "count": 3,
        "data":
            [
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9565226",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.70730989999993"
                },
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9550587",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.68279819999998"
                },
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9824",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.6927990"
                }
            ]
        };
    $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
        if(res['status']=='success'){
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(1, 1);
            // calculateAndDisplayRoute() START HERE 
            function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                var latitdute = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLatitidute);
                var longitude = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLongitude);
                var waypts = [];
                for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
                    waypts.push(
                        {
                            location: {
                                lat: latitdute,
                                lng: longitude
                            },
                            stopover: true
                        }
                    );
                }
                console.log(waypts);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
    <select name="tripId">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="btn-submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

My expected result:

```
[
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9565226,
            "lng": 77.70730989999993
        },
        "stopover": true
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9550587,
            "lng": 77.68279819999998
        },
        "stopover": true
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9824,
            "lng": 77.692799
        },
        "stopover": true
    }
]
[
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9565226,
            "lng": 77.70730989999993
        },
        "stopover": true
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9550587,
            "lng": 77.68279819999998
        },
        "stopover": true
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9824,
            "lng": 77.692799
        },
        "stopover": true
    }
]
[
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9565226,
            "lng": 77.70730989999993
        },
        "stopover": true
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9550587,
            "lng": 77.68279819999998
        },
        "stopover": true
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "lat": 12.9824,
            "lng": 77.692799
        },
        "stopover": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is nested inside your `each` loop and you were redeclaring `waypts` as an empty array each iteration.

I have moved your `var waypts=[];` declaration outside of `each()` and removed your inner `for` loop entirely.

```js
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var res={
        "status": "success",
        "count": 3,
        "data":
            [
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9565226",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.70730989999993"
                },
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9550587",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.68279819999998"
                },
                {
                    "tripId": "1",
                    "pickUpLatitidute": "12.9824",
                    "pickUpLongitude": "77.6927990"
                }
            ]
        };
    if(res['status']=='success'){
        var waypts=[];
        for (i=0; i<res['count']; ++i) {
            var temp=[];
            $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
                calculateAndDisplayRoute(1, 1);
                // calculateAndDisplayRoute() START HERE 
                function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                    var latitdute = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLatitidute);
                    var longitude = JSON.parse(value.pickUpLongitude);
                    temp.push(
                        {
                            location: {
                                lat: latitdute,
                                lng: longitude
                            },
                            stopover: true
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
            waypts.push(temp);
        }
        console.log(waypts);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
    <select name="tripId">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="btn-submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If this doesn't provide the desired output, please leave me a comment.

Comment: @please see my updated answer, i need like this ,previously i posted wrong please check and update the code

Comment: Why do you want to store redundant data like that?

Comment: For my requirement like that only, thats why

Comment: I have updated the answer to use a fresh temporary array which is pushed into `waypts` after each inner loop concludes.  Is this what you want?  Your expected result was not formatted like a valid array.

Comment: How to take the array count,instead  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { } // 3, i want  to give dynamic like object count

Comment: I have added `res['count']` to the for loop, assuming that's what you mean.

Comment: @MilanChheda that was a rather useless answer edit.  Are you just trying to get your edit count up?

Comment: No, I not increasing my counts, but I wonder why was it useless? I just tidy-ed it, so that its well-formatted and readable.